# How do I globalize a variable in a function without the global keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a function using while True loop, try/except to ask someone's name. The requirements are I have to pass in at least 1 parameter, I will use `input()` to ask their name using the while True loop (asks until I get a valid name). Try/except will help me to detect if the user types in a valid name (words only) or an invalid name (letters and numbers or numbers only). Then I have to return that valid name variable so I can use it later on in my full program.

Here is the code:

```
name=('')
def customername(name):
  while True:
        try:
              name = input("What's your name?\n")
              if len(name) >= 2 and name.isalpha():
                    print('\nHi, {}'.format(name))
                    break
              else:
                    raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
              print("\nOnly letters allowed, your name must contain 2 or more letters and no space needed!\n")

print(customername(name))
```

Comment: Why do you need a global variable? Have you learned about return values yet?

Comment: It is not really possible to make a variable global after the function has been defined. You can technically still write into the global scope if you really want to (`globals()`), but you really don't want to do that. Why can't you use the `global` keyword? Why do you not want to use return values?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `global` variable. You can make use of [`return`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/) keyword to store the value and use further in your program.

```
def customername():
  while True:
        try:
              name = input("What's your name?\n")
              if len(name) >= 2 and name.isalpha():
                    print('\nHi, {}'.format(name))
                    break
              else:
                    raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
              print("\nOnly letters allowed, your name must contain 2 or more letters and no space needed!\n")
  return name

name = customername()
print(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

it is a function so when you call the function from outside, you can do some_name = customername(name) and then some_name can be used anywhere in the code.

Comment: he doesn't really want a global variable. He just wants to use the "name" outside the function. Shouldn't focus too much on the wording. Should focus more on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but it could be a comment on the question. At the moment the question doesn't even seem clear (Does the OP know about returning values from functions? Is there a reason they want to use global variables instead of returning values that we don't know? Is there really a reason they want to make a variable global inside a function after the fact?), so no good answer might be able to exist.